# Understanding the statement "orbifold theories are QFTs with finite gauge group"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, path-integral, gauge-invariance

I'd like to understand the equivalence of orbifold theories in string theory and (2D worldsheet) QFTs with finite gauge group, using the path integral.

Suppose my action is $$S= \frac{1}{2\pi \alpha'} \int d^2\sigma  (\partial_i X^\mu \partial^i X_\mu)$$ and the $X^\mu(\sigma)$ are invariant under some finite group action $\Gamma$. To construct the orbifold theory on a Riemann surface $\Sigma$, I want to take the path integral over the untwisted and twisted sectors, i.e. I want to average over all boundary conditions on $X^\mu$ in which $X^\mu$ is periodic up to $\Gamma$-action.

Now, on the other hand, if I want to compute the path integral of a QFT with a finite gauge group, I would "gauge-fix" and *then* compute the path integral.

How can I see that the two approaches are the same?

Comment: When the gauge group is finite, does computing the path-integral require fixing the gauge? If not, then does the question remain if gauge-fixing isn't used?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Good question, I am not sure. Indeed gauge-fixing may not be required for finite groups, or the gauge redundancy may only contribute an overall factor. As for the second question-- yes, regardless, I can't understand how the path integral of a QFT with a finite gauge group relates to the path integral prescription for an orbifold theory, with all its twisted boundary conditions and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with how to couple to a *finite* gauge field in the continuum language (i.e., I am not sure how to write down the minimal coupling/covariant derivative). But I can answer your question for lattice gauge theories. Perhaps that is already helpful---and perhaps you can see how to generalize it to a continuum description?

Your question is about a two-dimensional spacetime. So in the context of lattice gauge theories, we can work with a one-dimensional chain. As a concrete example, let us consider the quantum Ising chain:
$$ H = \sum_{n=1}^N \left( X_n X_{n+1} + g \; Z_n \right), $$
where I use $X,Y,Z$ to denote the Pauli matrices. This model has a global $\mathbb Z_2$ symmetry $P = \prod_n Z_n$ and is defined on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H_\textrm{sites}$ consisting of $N$ spin-$1/2$ degrees of freedom. I will now explain how orbifolding this or gauging it lead to the same result.

### Orbifolding the Ising chain

Orbifolding corresponds to projecting onto invariant states, as well as summing over boundary conditions:
$$ H_\textrm{orb} = \lambda X_1 X_N + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} X_n X_{n+1} +  g \sum_{n=1}^N Z_n \qquad \textrm{with constraint } \prod_n Z_n  = 1, $$
where $\lambda = \pm 1$ is a new quantum-mechanical degree of freedom (labeling the periodic/antiperiodic bc's). What I mean by this constraint is that we should think of $H_\textrm{orb}$ being defined on the Hilbert space
$$\mathcal H_\textrm{orb} = \left\{ |\psi\rangle \in \mathcal H_\textrm{sites} \otimes \mathcal H_\textrm{bc} \; \;\left| \; \; \prod_{n=1}^N Z_n |\psi\rangle = |\psi \rangle \right. \right\} ,$$
where $\mathcal H_\textrm{bc}$ denotes the two-level Hilbert space labeled by $\lambda = \pm 1$.

### Gauging the Ising chain

Gauging corresponds to coupling it minimally to a $\mathbb Z_2$ gauge field that lives on the links of the original lattice. Let us denote the Pauli matrices on the links as $\sigma^{x,y,z}$. Then:
$$ H_\textrm{gauge} = \sum_{n=1}^N \left( X_n \sigma^z_{n+1/2} X_{n+1} + g \; Z_n \right) \textrm{ with constraint } G_n := \sigma^x_{n-1/2} Z_n \sigma^x_{n+1/2} = 1.$$
The local constraint implements the Gauss law. More precisely, $H_\textrm{gauge}$ is defined on the Hilbert space
$$\mathcal H_\textrm{gauge} = \left\{ |\phi\rangle \in \mathcal H_\textrm{sites} \otimes \mathcal H_\textrm{links}\; \;\left| \; \; \forall n \in \{1,2,\cdots, N\}:G_n |\phi\rangle = |\phi \rangle \right. \right\} .$$
For convenience, I am imagining a periodic system (i.e., no boundaries).

### Connecting the two by gauge fixing

Gauge fixing means that we (partially) specify the configuration of the gauge fields; this comes at the price of breaking gauge invariance, but the physical gauge invariant state can always be obtained by gauge-symmetrizing.

Let us make this concrete for, say, the link variable between sites $1$ and $2$. For any gauge-invariant state $|\psi \rangle \in \mathcal H_\textrm{gauge}$, we can project this link variable to point up: $|\psi'\rangle := P^\uparrow_{3/2} |\psi \rangle$ where $P^\uparrow_{n+1/2} := \frac{1 + \sigma^z_{n+1/2}}{2}$ projects a link variable onto $|\uparrow \rangle_{n+1/2}$. This also means that this state is *not* gauge-invariant, i.e., $|\psi'\rangle \notin \mathcal H_\textrm{gauge}$. Instead, we say it is *gauge-fixed*. However, no information has been lost: the original state can be recovered by gauge-symmetrizing: $|\psi\rangle = (1+G_2) |\psi'\rangle$. Indeed, this is a simple consequence from $G_2 P_{3/2}^\uparrow = (1-P_{3/2}^\uparrow) G_2$ and the gauge-invariance of $G_2 |\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$.

<sub>As an aside, one can actually derive the normalization of $|\psi'\rangle$:</sub>
$$ \scriptsize \langle \psi' |\psi' \rangle = \langle \psi | P^\uparrow_{3/2} | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | G_2 P^\uparrow_{3/2}  | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | \left( 1- P^\uparrow_{3/2}  \right) G_n | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | \psi\rangle - \langle \psi' |\psi' \rangle \quad \Rightarrow \quad \langle \psi' |\psi' \rangle  = \frac{1}{2} \langle \psi | \psi\rangle.$$

One can similarly project the link variable between sites $2$ and $3$, which can be undone using $(1+G_3)$, and one can keep doing this all the way to the link between sites $N-1$ and $N$ (using $G_N$), obtaining the gauge-fixed state:
$$ |\psi_\textrm{fix}\rangle = \sqrt{2}^{N-1} \prod_{n=1}^{N-1} P^\uparrow_{n+1/2} |\psi\rangle \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^{N-1}} \prod_{n=2}^N (1+G_n) |\psi_\textrm{fix} \rangle$$

The gauge-fixed wavefunction has almost all link variables being polarized into a product state, *except* for the link between sites $N$ and $1$ (let us denote this link as $N+1/2 = 1/2$). Indeed, if we would apply the projector $P_{1/2}^\uparrow$, we would lose information since we can no longer argue that $(1+G_1)$ would undo this projection: it acts non-trivially only the link between sites $1$ and $2$, which would screw up our earlier argument that we can undo that projection $P_{3/2}$ et cetera.

The gauge-fixed wavefunction thus has one link variable left. The effective Hamiltonian on this gauge-fixed wavefunction looks like
$$ H_\textrm{fix} = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}  X_n X_{n+1} + X_N \sigma^z_{1/2} X_1 + g \sum_{n=1}^N Z_n. $$
This looks exactly like our orbifold Hamiltonian, $H_\textrm{orb}$! Indeed, if we simply omit the polarized link variables in our description, we see that our Hilbert space of gauge-fixed states is simply $\mathcal H_\textrm{orb}$ if we identify $\lambda = \sigma^z_{1/2}$. To fact that our gauge-fixed states satisfy $\prod_n Z_n = +1$ follows from the fact that the original state obeys this (since  $\prod_n Z_n = \prod_n G_n$) and our projectors commute with $\prod_n Z_n$. Conversely, we can see that any state of this orbifold space gives a gauge-invariant state after acting with $\prod_{n=2}^N (1+G_n)$: by construction this state is invariant under $G_{n=2,\cdots,N}$, as for $G_1$ simply observe that $G_1 = \prod_{n=2}^N G_n \times \prod_{n=1}^N Z_n$.